# How to set a default filter option in Algolia Instant Search

Tags: react-native, algolia, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

I want to display only certain records from Algolia.For that I need to filter the list with some Ids (which I will get from some other api).The records has to displayed on page load .Is there any option I can use to filter the list that dont reflect in connectCurrentRefinements?

```
<InstantSearch
      searchClient={searchClient}
      indexName="STRAPI_SL_CAR"
      searchState={this.state.searchState}
      onSearchStateChange={this.onSearchStateChange}
    >
</InstantSearch>
```

Comment: Have you solved that issue or found a solution?